# Facebook iOS app won't connect unless wi-fi enabled

Tags: facebook, ios

I recently download the Facebook app for iOS. It doesn't connect to the internet unless wi-fi is enabled. All other apps are able to connect to the internet with wi-fi disabled, just not Facebook. I am running iOS 9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible thing that I could think of is that you may have disabled maybe accidently Cellular Data for Facebook and to verify you could go into **Settings -> Cellular** and verify that under *USE CELLULAR DATA FOR:* is turned on for Facebook.

Another rare possibility could be that there might be a DNS issue with your cellular data provider whereas it wouldn't be able to reach Facebook on its own network.

Comment: cell data was turned off for the facebook app